# Weird array output in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

The content extracted from the file is separated and stored in an array, and print the content using loop. Only printing the last element is weird. I'll show you my code.
How can I resolve this problem?

[config.json]

```
{ 
  "id": "hello",
  "passwd": "1234",
  "languageList": ["ko", "en"]
}
```

[test.sh]

```
# BEFORE_CONFIG and AFTER_CONFIG have same code
BEFORE_CONFIG=~/workspace/env/config.json
AFTER_CONFIG=~/workspace/config/config.json

BEF_LANG=$(grep "\[" ${BEFORE_CONFIG} | tr -d '\[' | tr -d '\]' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2)
AF_LANG=$(grep "\[" ${AFTER_CONFIG} | tr -d '\[' | tr -d '\]' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2)

echo "before lang :: ${BEF_LANG}"
echo "after lang :: ${AF_LANG}"


IFS=',' read -r -a AF_LANG_LIST <<< "$AF_LANG"

echo "after lang list print >> ${AF_LANG_LIST[@]}"
echo "list length >> ${#AF_LANG_LIST[@]}"


for element in ${AF_LANG_LIST[@]}
do
            echo "${element}"
            echo "This language !!! ${element} !!! print !!!!"
done
```

[result]

```
$ source tesh.sh

before lang :: ko,en
after lang :: ko,en
after lang list >> ko en
list length >> 2
ko
This language !!! ko !!! print !!!!
en
 !!! print !!!!!! en   # expect result → This language !!! en !!! print !!!!
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The expected results are as follows.
 !!! print !!!!!! en → This language !!! en !!! print !!!!

Comment: Please add the expected result in your question, so we can replicate it. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added the expected result in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jq` to parse the json correctly, and extract `languageList` do:

```
cat ~/workspace/env/config.json|jq .languageList[] -r|xargs
```

which will output:

```
ko en
```

which you can later use in your script

Trying to parse JSON with `tr` & `cut` is prone to so many errors.

Here is the example for your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# BEFORE_CONFIG and AFTER_CONFIG have same code
BEFORE_CONFIG=~/workspace/env/config.json
AFTER_CONFIG=~/workspace/config/config.json

BEF_LANG=$(grep "\[" ${BEFORE_CONFIG} | tr -d '\[' | tr -d '\]' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2)
#AF_LANG=$(grep "\[" ${AFTER_CONFIG} | tr -d '\[' | tr -d '\]' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2)

AF_LANG=$(cat ${BEFORE_CONFIG}|jq .languageList[] -r|xargs)

echo "before lang :: ${BEF_LANG}"
echo "after lang :: ${AF_LANG}"

# you do not need this
#IFS=',' read -r -a AF_LANG_LIST <<< "$AF_LANG"

#echo "after lang list print >> ${AF_LANG_LIST[@]}"
#echo "list length >> ${#AF_LANG_LIST[@]}"


for element in ${AF_LANG[@]}
do
            echo "${element}"
            echo "This language !!! ${element} !!! print !!!!"
done
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but failed... I already installed jq. AF_LANG_LIST has one element(ko en).

Comment: AF_LANG_LIST is not even needed in your code

Comment: I fixed my code and tried again. But result is same.. AF_LANG has one element.

Comment: The script works. with the given input file, it lists both languages. Please tripple-check what you are doing and maybe start over? and check all of your steps.. and input data..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resolved this problem. The problem is carriage return. I remove carrage return and print normally.